# Can useParams be able to use inside App.js?

Tags: reactjs, parameters, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Good day, hoping that I am not bothering you guys.

---

#### Details

I have a path like this

**localhost:3000/Project-1/todo-1**

and Switch of Route like this

```
<Route path='/:project/:todo' component={Todo} />
```

---

#### Expected Output

When browser is in the example path, what I expected is App.js can also **get params object** by using **useParams** but shows empty. Did I misuse the hook? Thank you for the answers.

---

#### Additional Details

I did use **useLocation** that returns something like path but that is not my aim, it should be something like

```
params: { 
  project: 'Project-1', 
  todo: 'todo-1 '
}
```

that is returned using **useParams** for ease of extraction of project and todo values

Comment: Can you show us your `Todo` component?

Comment: @technicallynick good day, I guess it has nothing to do with Todo component but still I will show it screencast.com/t/qbDbM2UeAb7

Comment: I'm confused by your statement that it has nothing to do with Todo. `useParams` is intended to be called from within the component being rendered by `<Route />`, just as you have in your `Todo` component. Are you saying that if you `console.log(params.project, params.todo)`, nothing is returned in your console? If so, then I would say a codesandbox for us to see would be the next step. I'm seeing nothing wrong in your `Todo` component.

Comment: `useParams` can only work in your `Todo` component or it's subtree, you are trying it from `App.js` and hence the `undefined`

Comment: @technicallynick pardon for the confusion I just put <Route> that confuses you, because on Todo component useParams works well.

Comment: @Agney thank you, is there other way to get a param object?

Comment: @Agney thanks for the answer, you can post it as the answer we'll mark it the correct one

Answer (score 2):

I believe `Route` injects props to components it renders, so you should be able to pull it straight from the `match` prop within `Todo`: `this.props.match.params`.

You’ll have access to match objects in various places:

- **Route component as this.props.match**
- Route render as ({ match }) => ()
- Route children as ({ match }) => ()
- withRouter as this.props.match
- matchPath as the return value

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match

This only works for components rendered *within* a router on a route, i.e. ***the*** component a `Route` is rendering, or a child component further down the DOM tree. If `App.js` is rendering the router it won't have it.

If you need to do something with route params in the root `App.js` you can wrap it in a route, with unspecified path so it matches all routes, in your router using the render prop. Just ensure this is rendered outside any `Switch` components though as switches **only** return the first match, not all matches.

```
<Route
  render={({ match }) => {
    console.log('match', match);
    // do what you need with the `match` prop, i.e. `match.params`
    return null; // return null to indicate nothing should actually be rendered
  }}
/>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I guess you mean about getting it inside Todo right? Sorry, but It has nothing to do with it. What I aiming for is App.js. I tried function(props) { ... but still undefined

Comment: Is `App.js` rendered within a route? If not then there is not route information for it.

Comment: No, it is the root

Comment: @AljohnYamaro Sorry for misunderstanding your original question. I've updated my answer to show how to access route details within your root component.

Comment: @DrewReese's edited answer is the correct one. To hammer in a point a little finer though, make sure you're using the `render` prop in `Route` and not the `component` prop when using an inline function. The `component` prop will force a full remount of the component on every render rather than updating it. I only mention this as your example is using `component` while @DrewReese is correctly using `render`. I didn't want you to overlook that small but significant change.

Comment: thank you for the edit, I appreciate that, I tried it inside App.js before Switch and also I tried it inside index.js js that returns null and tried also returning <App /> unfortunately, still param is undefined

Comment: @AljohnYamaro Mind updating your question with what you've tried and where you are still stuck?

Comment: @DrewReese sorry for late response, I got it now useParams can only be used except in the App.js as what Agney said