# Get url as object in react

Tags: reactjs, object, url, path, react-hooks

How can we get url as object not string.

This is my sample code below.

App.js

```
return (
 <Switch>
  <Route path='/:company/:project/:todo' component={Project} />
  <Route path='/:company/:project' component={Project} />
  <Route path='/:company' component={Projects} />
 </Switch>
)
```

For example when a url is like **companyxyz/project0/todo0**. Somewhere in any of the components can get

```
{
  company: companyxyz,
  project: project0,
  todo: todo0
}
```

Another example is **companyxyz/project0**. Then it will create like this.

```
{
  company: companyxyz,
  project: project0
}
```

As the examples above match their corresponding Route and map into object as Route is keys and Url is values

I use **useLocation()** but it returns a pathname with a url in string. I also use **useParams()** but returns empty object.

Comment: Why not creating a own object based on useLocation?

Comment: @DamianBusz good day, how can we do that?

Comment: there you go https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: @DamianBusz, Thank you for the help, I guess this won't work this way. I tried this before but I can't remember if I was using a hook that will map key to value based on Route path as keys and value that is from the url. Through that, it will create an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is useParams() that can give us the expected results. The problem was, I use useParams() inside App.js which on this thread [Can useParams be able to use inside App.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59581817/can-useparams-be-able-to-use-inside-app-js) can answer it.

For summary, **useParams can only give us the object when we use it except in App.js**